# How to hide off-screen images?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to increase my page speed and the page speed is reduced because of the images in the page. I want to make it so that when an image goes off-screen, I want to hide that image or load it only when it is on-screen.

I can already check if the element is off-screen, I want to know how to hide images when it goes offscreen.

Comment: I would think that once an image has loaded, any code to remove it or hide it will probably make matters worse, as you'll then need more code to load/show it again etc.  This is the sort of optimisation that should probably be (and probably is being) done at the browser level - I would expect its rendering engine to take care of off-screen elements.

Comment: You can iterate over all images and if it's offscreen remove src attribute and add data-src with the value and when image is visible (you can use scroll event) you can add src attribute back.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What do you mean 'page-speed'. Are you talking about the time it takes to load the page, or about the speed of certain dynamic elements on your page?

Comment: @jcubic's suggestion won't improve your load time, becasue the images will already have started loading before you start running through removing the src attributes.   You'd have to remove the src attributes in the html document *before* the page is loaded by the user, not via javascript after load.

Comment: If you are using jquery already, look at @tomastley answer.  It will keep it from loading until it's in view.  Once the loading process starts, just let it be.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest thing to do would be use a lazy loader like this one: http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload

You can configure it so that when the image is in view it will then start to load. That way your initial load time would be reduced.